# Calculating Project End Date

Tags: 2013, calculated-column-formula

In the project I'm working on I have created a column called `Project Delivery` `Start Date` and a column called `Delivery Days`.

I want to use the start date and delivery days to create the Project Delivery Start Date, but need to include the formula

```
=if([Delivery Days >=6, [Project Start Date]+[Delivery Days]+2, else if(([Delivery Days >=10, [Project Start Date]+[Delivery Days]+4))
```

The reason I want this is if the project has 6 delivery days I need to have 2 extra days to cover the weekend, as these dates will be used to create calendar entries later on

But I keep getting errors

Comment: I don't get why you wouldn't just make a delivery date column and use that. In any case that your date slips, you specify the new delivery date instead of specifying a new days value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this to add 4 , 2 or 0 days

```
=[Project Start Date] + [Delivery Days]
  + IF( [Delivery Days] > 9
        , 4
        , IF( [Delivery Days] > 5
              , 2
              , 0
            )
      )
```

And if you want to calculate "For Every Week Add 2 days" look into the MOD function

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Answer (score 0):

First thing, that catches my eyes is, that you don't seem to close some of the brackets....

```
=IF( [Delivery Days] >=6
     , [Project Start Date]+[Delivery Days]+2
     , IF( [Delivery Days] >=10
           , [Project Start Date]+[Delivery Days]+4
           , ?????
         )
    )
```

Also there seems to be a calculation gap where you don't give a value.

Essentially what you showed us is this (this is not real code):

```
if ([Delivery Days] >= 6)
  [Project Start Date]+[Delivery Days]+2
else
  if ([Delivery Days] >=10) 
    [Project Start Date]+[Delivery Days]+4
```

But that does not work, your second constraint will never be reached...

Comment: Sidenote: I mostly write my formulas in Excel and then convert them once they're done. Excel is much more helpfull than SharePoint.

Comment: You can make the SharePoint Calculated Column editor more helpful: https://github.com/Danny-Engelman/CalcMaster

Comment: Yes there is a ???? gap in the formula, but an else branch is not required as SharePoint will return a FALSE value by default. The 6 and 10 days should indeed be reversed